# Can arrays overlap (alias), or is GCC being overly cautious?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, strict-aliasing

For the following C++ code, GCC 8.3 and Clang 7.0 (both with -O2) generate a call to memmove unless compiling with -DRESTRICT.  With -DRESTRICT, faster code is generated (either "rep movsq" or memcpy).

I think the check `if (&dest != &src)` is enough to prove there is no aliasing.  Are GCC and Clang missing a trick here, or is it legal in C++ for there to be aliasing even with this check (e.g. by casting two overlapping sections of a larger array to get src and dest)?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

typedef int Arr[100];

inline void Copy(Arr& __restrict__ dest, const Arr& __restrict__ src)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), dest);
}

void f2(Arr& dest, const Arr& src)
{
    if (&dest != &src) // make sure there is no aliasing
    {
#ifdef RESTRICT
        Copy(dest, src); // generates better code, why?
#else
        std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), dest);
#endif
    }
}
```

Live: https://godbolt.org/z/3UmkWm

Comment: It isn't specifically arrays, even with just 2 int pointers gcc does not use a test `a!=b` to rule out aliasing. Not that this would be impossible, but it seems harder to implement than one might expect. Also, did you measure a significant speed difference between memmove and memcpy? I always expected it to matter, and it never did when I went though the trouble of getting memcpy.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: In Clang it's memcpy, but in GCC we get `rep movsq` and if the data is smaller we get just a few `mov`s.  See what happens if the size is 3 instead of 100: https://godbolt.org/z/mT18Hb - surely 3 `mov`s are faster than a call to `memmove`.

Comment: I don't find a legal way for 2 arrays to overlap (as "splitting" and casting  `int buffer[150]` into 2 (overlapping) arrays would be UB). so for me it is guaranty that `src` and `dest` doesn't alias (with `&dest != &src`). That detection is probably not implemented.

Comment: @jarod42: Gcc compiles this without warnings: [`f2(*(Arr*)&bigger[0], *(Arr*)(&bigger[50]));`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7709190fffe9d1c). Is that illegal? Do you have a standard citation? (I'm prepared to believe either way; just curious.)

Comment: @rici: clang produces warning: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/976b52428ac2e672) about UB.

Comment: @Jarod42: That's true, but check this out, using two overlapping parts of a char array, cast to structs as is commonly done in high performance network message parsing code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08a46e6cd655d8fc - no warnings.  This is the sort of thing I was concerned about, and might be enough to mean that GCC can't assume no aliasing just because the addresses of the first elements differ.

Comment: For me it is UB as it is not a `S` neither at `c` nor `c + 8`. You need placement new, but then you cannot overlap neither....

Comment: @Jarod42: I agree, so I filed a GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89617